# Terraform plan after fetching terraform configuration

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, terraform

I use terraform with aws provider.

It seems like terraform should has state file for updating resources. When I commit my terraform configuration to git from one PC, and fetch it from another PC, `terraform plan` wants to create all resources, albeit resources were actually created on another PC. How to fix this without committing state file to git?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is Infra-as-Code which requires management of statefile. For AWS Cloud, the most popular choice is AWS S3 bucket. [Here is more on terraform state management](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/index.html)

1. Create an S3 bucket to store State files.
2. Ensure it has appropriate permissions
3. In your Terraform code, [reference the S3 bucket as backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Remote State](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) in such a situation. If you are using AWS, you can use [s3 backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html) to store the state in a bucket of your choice. Example from docs:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Terraform provides a lot of examples and use-case scenarios on how to setup and use such backend, and most importantly how to [Protect Access to Workspace State](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html#protecting-access-to-workspace-state).

Other backend are also possible, such as Terraform Cloud, Azure Blob Storage, Google Cloud Storage, Alibaba Cloud OSS, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Managing the backend state is very important. Sounds like your .gitignore file is excluding your local state file? Typically these lines are in .gitignore for terraform:

```
# Local .terraform directories
**/.terraform/*

# .tfstate files
*.tfstate
*.tfstate.*
```

If you take out the state file lines above, that means you will check them out on another PC & maintain the same state. But as mentioned, remotely managing your state files is ideal.